# JS array of objects formatting

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, js-beautify

I'm trying to set up a custom formatter using the [`js-beautify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) node package, but I'm running into an issue when formatting an array of objects.  I want my output to look like this:

```js
{
  someFunction: function() {

  },

  arr: [{
    thing: 1
  }, {
    one: 2
  }]
}
```

You'll notice that my braces are on the same line as another brace or bracket.  However, I've noticed that if my code contains a format like this, it formats incorrectly:

```js
// Formatted input
{
    someFunction: function() {

    },

    arr: [{
        thing: 1
    },
     {
        one: 2
    }]
}

// Formatted output
{
    someFunction: function() {

    },

    arr: [{
            thing: 1
        },
        {
            one: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought `"brace_style": "end-expand"` would be what I wanted, but it appears not to work for this case.  It's weird because if I had something like the below, it would format properly on [the online beautifier](https://beautifier.io/):

```js
{
    someFunction: function() {

    },

    arr: [{
        thing: 1
    },     {
        one: 2
    }]
}
```

Anybody have any suggestions how to get my desired output?  I'm assuming there's some config property I can set.  Also, if someone has a better node package or formatter, I'd be entertaining that as well.

**EDIT**
From Adnan Sharif's first suggestion, it looks like `"preserve_newlines": true` is the reason why this is happening, but if I remove that, then I lose all of my newlines... this seems a little troubling if I can't preserve all of my newlines due to brace formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to this would be to use ESLint and [my package's](https://github.com/incutonez/eslint-plugin) overrides for the rules `array-bracket-newline` and `array-element-newline`.

Answer (score 3):

I have pasted your JSON string with the JSON options -

```
{
  "indent_size": "2",
  "indent_char": " ",
  "max_preserve_newlines": "-1",
  "preserve_newlines": false,
  "keep_array_indentation": false,
  "break_chained_methods": false,
  "indent_scripts": "keep",
  "brace_style": "collapse",
  "space_before_conditional": false,
  "unescape_strings": false,
  "jslint_happy": false,
  "end_with_newline": false,
  "wrap_line_length": "0",
  "indent_inner_html": false,
  "comma_first": false,
  "e4x": false,
  "indent_empty_lines": false
}
```

It works as you said!

You may try to tweak the above settings according to your need. Thanks!

Comment: So it seems my issue is with the property `"preserve_newlines": true`, and if I switch this to false, yes, this works, but then I lose all of my newlines...